# Does anyone have any information about the new E Visas for tourist entry into Kuwait?

Tags: visas, kuwait, e-visas

I saw an article some time back on Kuwait launching E Visas for specific nationalities but when I went through the process described - it still came across as a Visa on arrival - although there is an online form to get the data sent to the MOI.
Plus I also believe that one can apply through Kuwait Airlines, in person or the sponsor in Kuwait can apply for you?
If anyone has any specific information on this - would help.

Comment: kindly mention your nationality.

Comment: Portuguese. I checked and I am eligible to apply for an E Visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kuwait's system is similar to what has been deployed in the UAE.

It allows you to apply online for the visa, and then collect it (rather, get it stamped or entered) when you arrive at the border.

The process is outlined at [this page](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/home_e.do); along with the restrictions and approvals.  You can apply on your own (start [here](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/visaPubApp10.do?lng=eng)), you don't need a sponsor to apply on your behalf.

The "E" in the e-visa means that you are no longer given a paper document or required to carry one with you.